# Use class in the test's inlineData

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

I have used the following class as my Mocked class:

```
public class MockData
{
    public static MockData Current { get; } = new MockData();
    public List<ClientViewModel> Choices { get; set; }

    public MockData()
    {
        Choices = new List<ClientViewModel>
        {
            new ClientViewModel { Answers = new[] { false, false, false } },
            new ClientViewModel { Answers = new[] { true, true, true } },
            new ClientViewModel { Answers = new[] { true, true, false } },
            new ClientViewModel { Answers = new[] { true, false, true } },
            new ClientViewModel { Answers = new[] { true, false, false } }
        };
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to test the above user choices to see if each instance of `ClientViewModel` class give me the expected string answer. To achieve this I have used the following test method:

```
[Fact]
public void ClientRequest_UserChoicesPassed_ReturnsRightAnswer()
{
    // Arrange
    var clientViewModel = MockData.Current.Choices[0];

    // Act
    var jsonResult = _controller.ClientRequest(clientViewModel) as JsonResult;

    // Assert
    string expectedAnswer = "It is a book";
    Assert.Equal(expectedAnswer, ((ResultDTO)jsonResult.Value).Result);
}
```

This works perfectly and my test is passed as expected. However my problem with this approach is that I have to repeat this test for other entries as well, as you noticed I have used `var clientViewModel = MockData.Current.Choices[0];` in the `Arrange` section of the test, to test the first entry, I don't want to repeat myself by writing multiple tests for this purpose. I already aware of `[Theory]` and `[InlineData]` concepts in xNunit, however, it seems I have some difficulty with class, please see below:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(MockData.Current.Choices[0], "It is a book")]
[InlineData(MockData.Current.Choices[1], "It is a pen")]
public void ClientRequest_UserChoicesPassed_ReturnsRightAnswer(ClientViewModel clientViewModel, string expectedAnswer)
{
  //...
}
```

But this gives me the following exception:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

So please let me know, is there any way, I can do anything to prevent repeating this method?

Comment: As you've observed, you can't use non-constant data in an attribute. If you want to use dynamic data like this, you should use the `MemberDataAttribute` and provide a method that yields the test case data instead, or the `ClassDataAttribute` with a class that implements IEnumerable and returns your test case data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To accomplish this, you can use the `MemberDataAttribute` with a public static method that returns your test cases to be used. Here's an example:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetUserChoiceTestData() 
{
    yield return new object[] { MockData.Current.Choices[0], "It is a book" };
    yield return new object[] { MockData.Current.Choices[1], "It is a pen" };
}
```

Which, you would then apply to your test theory like so:

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(GetUserChoiceTestData))]
public void ClientRequest_UserChoicesPassed_ReturnsRightAnswer(ClientViewModel clientViewModel, string expectedAnswer)
{
  //...
}
```

This will work so long as the static method is a member of the test class you are running. If it's a member of another non-static class, you'll need to additionally provide that type to the `MemberDataAttribute`.

```
[MemberData(nameof(SomeOtherClass.GetUserChoiceTestData), MemberType = typeof(SomeOtherClass))]
```